# ajax.data form.serialize + myaction

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

Может вопрос глупый, но прошу помочь.. не могу найти решение.

Как передать все значения формы + `{ action: 'myaction' }`

```js
jQuery.ajax({
  type: form.attr('method'),
  url: myajax.url,
  data: {action: 'my_action'} + form.serialize(), // ошибка
  success: function(response){
    jQuery('.list').html(response);
  }
})
```

```php
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback');
function my_action_callback() {
 //...   
}
wp_die();
```

```php
// Переопределение ajaxurl
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myajax_data', 99 );
function myajax_data(){
wp_localize_script('myscript', 'myajax',
  array(
    'url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: POST http://localhost:3000/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: form.attr('method'),
        url: myajax.url,
        data: form.serialize()+'&action=my_action', 
        success: function(response){
            jQuery('.list').html(response);
    }
 })
```